# ASP SQL Server Date Range and DateTime field

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am using Classic ASP and have the following VB script code

```
From8to14 = date-14
To8to14 = date-8
```

This sets the two variables.

For today, this would mean that

```
From8to14 = "13/07/2012"
To8to14 = "19/07/2012"
```

I then have a select query to SQL server, and I want to find any records where the DateMatched column is between (and including) these two dates

I have two conditions in the SQL when I declare it;

```
"AND INTRAY.DateMatched >= '"& Year(From8to14) &"-"& Month(From8to14) &"-"& Day(From8to14) &"' " & _
"AND INTRAY.DateMatched <= '"& Year(To8to14) &"-"& Month(To8to14) &"-"& Day(To8to14) &"' " & _
```

Now, this is not working properly because DateMatched column also includes a time in addition to the date, and I think the server is interepreting these dates as being at midnight at the start of that day ?

So, if a record has a DateMatched of "19/07/2012 17:41:22" then it is not being included.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
"AND INTRAY.DateMatched >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-14, 0)" & _
"AND INTRAY.DateMatched < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-7, 0)" & _
```

Comment: +1 This one gets my vote, it smells better.  SQL composition through string concatenation should be minimised and challenged when used.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
To8to14 = date-8
```

to

```
To8to14 = date-7
```

Then you'll go from midnight on the -14th day to midnight on the -7th day, which will include all the -8th day.

Or if you want to be really precise, leave To8to14 as it is, and change the end to

```
... Day(To8to14) &" 23:59:59'
```

You could also use BETWEEN rather than >= and <=

Comment: +1 But he should use `>= and <` instead of `between`; the end date is exclusive